# How to display a name and score list for players using happyfuntimes and unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, installation

This is related to [happyfuntimes plugin](http://github.com/greggman/hft-unity3d) if you have used it .

I am trying to make a game on it and  stuck at a point of displaying score along with name  to  display on large screen  while user is playing on his mobile.(i have already tried to display name and score on mobile screens have seen in sample  do not need that ). Please suggest how can this be done if you have used happyfuntimes plugin.

I could see the HFTgamepad input having public GameObject player name which I am trying to access ,do I have to make array ?

```
public string playerName;
```

I am trying to put these name on array.

Comment: why not include a URL of the plugin in question?

Answer (score 0):

Displaying anything in unity is really normal unity issue and not special to happyfuntimes. Games display highscore lists, item lists, inventory lists, etc... A list of players is no different

[Use the GUI system display text](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-canvas).

[According to the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UICreateFromScripting.html) if you want to generate UI dynamically you should make a prefab

So basically you'd make a UI hierarchy in the scene. When a player is added to the game `Instantiate` your name-score prefab, search for the UI hierarchy gameObject (do that at init time), then set the parent of the preafab you just instantiated so it's in the UI hierarchy.

Look up the `UI.Text` components that represent name and score and set their `text` properties.

[There's various auto layout components to help layout your scores](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIAutoLayout.html)

When a player disconnects `Destroy` the prefab you instantiated above.

OR ...

Conversely you can use the old immediate mode GUI. You'd make a GameObject, give it a component that has a OnGUI function. Somewhere keep a list of players. Add players to the list as they connect and remove them from the list as they disconnect. In your OnGUI function loop over the list of players and call the [`GUI.Label`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Label.html) function or similar to draw each name and score

Here's a hacked up example.

Assuming you have a `PlayerScript` script component that's on each player that has a public accessor `PlayerName` for getting the player's name then you can make a GameObject and put a script like this on it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ExamplePlayerListGUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    static ExamplePlayerListGUI s_instance;
    List<PlayerScript> m_players = new List<PlayerScript>();

    static public ExamplePlayerListGUI GetInstance()
    {
        return s_instance;
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        if (s_instance != null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("there should only be one ExamplePlayerListGUI");
        }
        s_instance = this;
    }

    public void AddPlayer(PlayerScript bs)
    {
        m_players.Add(bs);
    }

    public void RemovePlayer(PlayerScript bs)
    {
        m_players.Remove(bs);
    }

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        Rect r = new Rect(0, 0, 100, m_players.Count * 20);
        GUI.Box(r, "");
        r.height = 20;
        foreach(var player in m_players)
        {
            GUI.Label(r, player.PlayerName);
            r.y += 20;
        }
    }
}
```

`PlayerScript` can then call `ExamplePlayerListGUI.GetInstance().AddPlayer` in its `Start` function and `ExamplePlayerListGUI.GetInstance().RemovePlayer` in it's `OnDestroy` function

```
public PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string m_playerName;  

    ...

    public string PlayerName
    {
        get 
        {
            return m_playerName;
        }
    }

    void Start() 
    {
        ...
        ExamplePlayerListGUI playerListGUI = ExamplePlayerListGUI.GetInstance();
        // Check if it exists so we can use it with or without the list
        if (playerListGUI != null)
        {
            playerListGUI.AddPlayer(this);
        }
    }

    void OnDestroy() 
    {
        ...

        ExamplePlayerListGUI playerListGUI = ExamplePlayerListGUI.GetInstance();
        if (playerListGUI != null)
        {
            playerListGUI.RemovePlayer(this);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: my issue displaying multiple player name and score ...yeah i am stuck at "keeping the list of player"  step above as mentioned (i am using OnGUI to display the name and score ..i  tried doing on array but in vain ......it would be very very helpfull if you help me with sample of using dynamic UI or with few lines of code for doing it ...tried alot ...seems i am doing some silly mistake.

Comment: added an example. Doing a GUI well is a lot of work in Unity. Settings fonts, picking styles or colors, using icons, etc. The code above is minimal and uses the old immediately mode GUI system.

Comment: You should not be promoting OnGui for using in games, Unity [explicitly states](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html) "*The IMGUI system is not generally intended to be used for normal in-game user interfaces that players might use and interact with.*". [Here is a simple tutorial](http://www.folio3.com/blog/creating-dynamic-scrollable-lists-with-new-unity-canvas-ui/) showing how to make a dynamic list using the correct canvas system for in game displays.

Comment: It was until version 4.6 :P  But in any case thanks for the link. The topic was arguably too big to post on SO so I used the OnGUI example since it's about 100x smaller just to get something working.

Comment: hi .. their was already one issue which i did not noticed and now after trying have seen it ..i am not able to see the player name on the  player ..(like we have in all the samples on the player ) ..i have seen code as well

Comment: hi .. their was already one issue which i did not noticed and now after trying have seen it ..i am not able to see the player name on the  player ..   i have seen code as well     `Vector2 size = m_guiStyle.CalcSize(m_guiName);                                Vector3 coords=Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(nameTransform.position);
        m_nameRect.x = coords.x - size.x * 0.5f - 5f;
        m_nameRect.y = Screen.height - coords.y;
        m_guiStyle.normal.textColor = Color.black;
        m_guiStyle.contentOffset = new Vector2(4, 2);
        GUI.Box(m_nameRect, m_playerName, m_guiStyle); `

Comment: it seems something i not setting correct in unity scene ?

Comment: finally all the issue have been solved ..the name not displaying properly on the character is due to name transform not at proper place according to the character used ...well thanks alot for the help